# Package does not exist - java/ant

Tags: java, xml, directory, ant, package

After recently trying to include a method from another package, I tried to run my program and I came across "error:package does not exist" in the cmd shell:

```
 [javac] C:\Users\Student\Desktop\JavaGame\src\cmet\ac\sockets\servers\ClientManager.java:9: error: package cmet.ac.sockets.clients does not exist
    [javac] import cmet.ac.sockets.clients.WriteToFile;
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Student\Desktop\JavaGame\src\cmet\ac\sockets\servers\ClientManager.java:10: error: package cmet.ac.sockets.clients does not exist
    [javac] import cmet.ac.sockets.clients.xmlparser;
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Student\Desktop\JavaGame\src\cmet\ac\sockets\servers\ClientManager.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             String s = WriteToFile.fullname;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable WriteToFile
    [javac]   location: class ClientManager
    [javac] C:\Users\Student\Desktop\JavaGame\src\cmet\ac\sockets\servers\ClientManager.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             int correctCount = xmlparser.correctCount;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable xmlparser
    [javac]   location: class ClientManager
    [javac] 4 errors
```

After reading online I've seen that i may need to add this separate package to my ant build file. I'm really not sure how to do this, I'm not very well versed in ant.

my ant file is as below:

```
<project name="SimpleServer" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir"     value="src/cmet/ac/sockets/servers"/>
    <property name="build.dir"   value="build_server"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class"  value="cmet.ac.sockets.servers.SimpleServer"/>


    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>

    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
            <arg value="${arg0}"/>
        </java>
    </target>



    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

how would i include the package it says does not exist? they are in two individual folders, but within the same src directory?

Comment: were you able to build locally? It looks like your import is giving the error.

Comment: No I cant, I get the same error strangely.

Comment: `import cmet.ac.sockets.clients.WriteToFile` is an external package so you have to make sure the package exist first and you are able to compile locally. After that, you shouldn't have a problem compiling via ant